# cant print the list after .copy() from dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, list, dataframe

I declared an empty list _Xs_pred and then am trying to copy a single column data frame into the list. The command runs without error but cant print the items of the list.
textual_data is a single column data frame with text values that are words concatenated with spaces. I get an error "unhashable list"

```
a = {'all_terms': ['Bus Sys Analyst Sr IT Information Technology IT-Merchandising It Information Technology',
'Retail Sales Specialist Retail  Retail-Camping Retail Stores',
'Operations Specialist Retail  Retail-Stocking Retail Stores',
'Sales Lead Retail  Retail-Sales Lead Retail Stores',
'Retail Sales Specialist Retail  Retail-Cashier Retail Stores']}

textual_data = pd.DataFrame(data=a)

_Xs_pred =  [None, None]
report=True
model_levels = [True, True, True]
idx_col = ['Data Order']
_levels = ['Level-1', 'Level-2', 'Level-3']

for i in range(2):
    if model_levels[i]:
        textual_data.index.name = idx_col
        _Xs_pred[i] = textual_data.copy()
        if report:
            print("ETL complete on {} data."
            .format(_levels[i]))
    else:
        continue

print(_Xs_pred)
```

i expect the output to be _Xs_pred having two columns with same textual_data. Currently i cant see anything in _Xs_pred

Comment: thank you for providing a code block that we can copy and use! Now, i am able to run the code just fine, no errors, and i am able to print the list without issues as well. Can you try running your code in a fresh kernel/session? what exactly are the issues you are facing?

Comment: Error is at "print(_Xs_pred)"
TypeError: unhashable type: 'list'

Comment: clear your kernel/session. and then *just* run the lines that you wrote here. My best guess is that you've accidentally overwritten `print` somewhere else. The code here runs just fine. i cannot reproduce any errors.

Comment: When i just paste the lines here, the code runs. But when i run the original code, which is creating textual_data dataframe from some other data frame, then the print command gives an error. Even though in both cases, column data type is "string".

Comment: so clearly, we cannot know from here what's wrong. but have you written a statement in the other code such as `print = something`? Regardless, we can only guess, you need to provide code that actually reproduces the problem too

Comment: Can you try to check your columns, if they really are string? e.g. by sum(textual_data['all_terms'].map(type) != str) maybe something nasty slipped into your dataframe.